# In R, a more elegant solution for finding "not-missing' values in one column, then adding a string based on these rows in a new variable?

Tags: r, na

In the multiple choice questions I have to analyze, there is an "other" option. For those where they can only pick one option, I will be uniting the separate columns of each answer choice into 1 column using unite. Wherever a person has written in an "other" string, instead of choosing one of the provided options, I want to change that row to say "Other."

For example:

```
ID   Sector1   Sector2     Sector3   ....  Sector13(Other)     
A    NA         NA         "String3"       NA
B    "String1"  NA          NA             NA  
C    "String1"  NA          NA             NA
D    NA         NA          NA             "Other string1"
E    NA         NA          NA             "Other string2"

ID NewSectorColumn
A  "String3"
B  "String1"
C  "String1"
D  "Other"
E  "Other"
```

Here's my code:
I first create the new variable ($SectorOther) in RawData1, then change the values of $SectorOther into "Other" if $Sector13  (the column which contains all the "other" answers) is not blank.

```
rawdata1$SectorOther <- rawdata1$sector13 
rawdata1$SectorOther [which(!is.na(rawdata1$SectorOther))] <- "Other Sector"
```

Just wondering if there is a more elegant solution, where I can combine doing the same thing to a few other variables like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `apply()` and a build-in function to organize your code like this. The `grepl()` function aims to detect the string with `other` word. Here the code:

```
#Code
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- x[min(which(!is.na(x)))]
  y <- ifelse(grepl('other',y,ignore.case = T),'Other',y)
  return(y)
}
#Apply
df$Newvar <- apply(df[,-1],1,myfun)
```

Output:

```
df
  ID Sector1 Sector2 Sector3 Sector13.Other.  Newvar
1  A    <NA>      NA String3            <NA> String3
2  B String1      NA    <NA>            <NA> String1
3  C String1      NA    <NA>            <NA> String1
4  D    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string1   Other
5  E    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string2   Other
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sector1 = c(NA, 
"String1", "String1", NA, NA), Sector2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Sector3 = c("String3", NA, NA, NA, NA), Sector13.Other. = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "Other string1", "Other string2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! Just going through the code to make sure I understand it: In the function, the new variable "y"  is created for the minimum row where "x" has a value (ie is not NA). Then, where grepl finds a string in (y) that contains "other", it turns "y" into the character string "other", ignoring the case. If it doesn't find it, it leaves it untouched. Then, in the apply function: you're applying it to the whole dataframe. 1 question is: shouldn't y start for all values of x (missing or not?) the other thing I forgot to mention is: I have several of these in my df, so apply all wouldn't work

Comment: @Pre It applies to all values in each row of the dataframe. Maybe if you can add another sample of data to test or adjust the code, it would be fine!

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```
indices <- cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(!is.na(df[-1]), 'first'))
df$New_col <- sub('(Other).*', '\\1', df[-1][indices])
df
  ID Sector1 Sector2 Sector3 Sector13.Other. New_col
1  A    <NA>      NA String3            <NA> String3
2  B String1      NA    <NA>            <NA> String1
3  C String1      NA    <NA>            <NA> String1
4  D    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string1   Other
5  E    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string2   Other
```

another option is to use ``coalesce`from`dplyr`:

```
df$NewSectorColumn <- sub("(Other).*","\\1",dplyr::coalesce(!!!df[-1]))
df
  ID Sector1 Sector2 Sector3 Sector13.Other. NewSectorColumn
1  A    <NA>      NA String3            <NA>         String3
2  B String1      NA    <NA>            <NA>         String1
3  C String1      NA    <NA>            <NA>         String1
4  D    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string1           Other
5  E    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string2           Other
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `fcoalecse` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewSectorColumn := sub("\\s+.*", "", 
     do.call(fcoalesce, lapply(.SD, as.character))),
          .SDcols = patterns('^Sector')]
```

-output

```
df
#   ID Sector1 Sector2 Sector3 Sector13.Other. NewSectorColumn
#1:  A    <NA>      NA String3            <NA>         String3
#2:  B String1      NA    <NA>            <NA>         String1
#3:  C String1      NA    <NA>            <NA>         String1
#4:  D    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string1           Other
#5:  E    <NA>      NA    <NA>   Other string2           Other
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Sector1 = c(NA, 
"String1", "String1", NA, NA), Sector2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Sector3 = c("String3", NA, NA, NA, NA), Sector13.Other. = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "Other string1", "Other string2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```